# Using existing conditions to simplify a certain part of polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Here, I want to simplify the polynomial P1

```
P1 == β (ω1 l2 + ω2 l1) + 2 γ ω1 ω2 + k1 (ω2 + 4 k2^3) + 
  k2 (ω1 + 4 k1^3) + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 6 l1 l2 + (k1^4 + k2^4 + k1 ω1 + 
  k2 ω2 + 3 l1^2 + 3 l2^2 + β (ω1 l1 + ω2 l2) + γ (ω1^2 + ω2^2))
```

under the conditions mentioned below

```
k1 ω1 + k1^4 + 3 l1^2 + γ ω1^2 + β ω1 l1 == 0 && 
 k2 ω2 + k2^4 + 3 l2^2 + γ ω2^2 + β ω2 l2 == 0
```

My code is

```
Assuming[
 k1 ω1 + k1^4 + 3 l1^2 + γ ω1^2 + β ω1 l1 == 0 && 
  k2 ω2 + k2^4 + 3 l2^2 + γ ω2^2 + β ω2 l2 == 0, 
 Simplify[(ω1 + ω2) (k1 + k2) + (k1 + k2)^4 + 
   3 (l1 + l2)^2 + γ (ω1 + ω2)^2 + β (ω1 + ω2) (l1 + l2)]]
```

It is obvious that the conditions make

```
(k1^4 + k2^4 + k1 ω1 + k2 ω2 + 3 l1^2 + 
  3 l2^2 + β (ω1 l1 + ω2 l2) + γ (ω1^2 + ω2^2))
```

equal to zero. Therefore, P1 should become

```
β (ω1 l2 + ω2 l1) + 2 γ ω1 ω2 + k1 (ω2 + 4 k2^3) + 
 k2 (ω1 + 4 k1^3) + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 6 l1 l2
```

However, the output looks different. How can I do such thing?

Cross-posted also on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3007578?p_p_auth=ms2MSbzA).

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = P1 == β (ω1 l2 + ω2 l1) + 
    2 γ ω1 ω2 + k1 (ω2 + 4 k2^3) + 
    k2 (ω1 + 4 k1^3) + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
    6 l1 l2 + (k1^4 + k2^4 + k1 ω1 + k2 ω2 + 3 l1^2 + 
      3 l2^2 + β (ω1 l1 + ω2 l2) + γ (\
ω1^2 + ω2^2));

c1 = k1 ω1 + k1^4 + 
    3 l1^2 + γ ω1^2 + β ω1 l1 == 0;
c2 = k2 ω2 + k2^4 + 
    3 l2^2 + γ ω2^2 + β ω2 l2 == 0;

FullSimplify[eq, c1 && c2] // Collect[#, {β, k1, k2}] &
```

> 4 k1^3 k2 + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 6 l1 l2 + k2 ω1 +    2 γ ω1 ω2 +    k1 (4
> k2^3 + ω2) + β (l2 ω1 + l1 ω2) ==   P1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Step1**:

```
sl = Solve[
   k1 ω1 + k1^4 + 
      3 l1^2 + γ ω1^2 + β ω1 l1 == 0 && 
    k2 ω2 + k2^4 + 
      3 l2^2 + γ ω2^2 + β ω2 l2 == 
     0, {β, γ}][[1]]

(*  {β -> -((-((k1^4 + 3 l1^2 + 
         k1 ω1) ω2^2) + ω1^2 (k2^4 + 3 l2^2 + 
       k2 ω2))/(
   l2 ω1^2 ω2 - 
    l1 ω1 ω2^2)), γ -> -((-k2^4 l1 ω1 - 
    3 l1 l2^2 ω1 + k1^4 l2 ω2 + 3 l1^2 l2 ω2 - 
    k2 l1 ω1 ω2 + 
    k1 l2 ω1 ω2)/(ω1 ω2 (l2 ω1 - 
      l1 ω2)))}  *)
```

**Step2**:

```
P1 = β (ω1 l2 + ω2 l1) + 
   2 γ ω1 ω2 + k1 (ω2 + 4 k2^3) + 
   k2 (ω1 + 4 k1^3) + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 
   6 l1 l2 + (k1^4 + k2^4 + k1 ω1 + k2 ω2 + 3 l1^2 + 
     3 l2^2 + β (ω1 l1 + ω2 l2) + γ (\
ω1^2 + ω2^2));

P1 /. sl // Simplify

  (*  4 k1^3 k2 + 6 k1^2 k2^2 + 4 k1 k2^3 - (k1^4 ω2)/ω1 - (k2^4 ω1^2 + 3 (l2 ω1 - l1 ω2)^2)/(ω1 ω2)  *)
```

Done. Have fun!